# Hide image map coordinates when javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagemap, noscript

I have an image map and I want to hide its clickable coordinates when Javascript is disabled, so that only the image is left. I tried using noscript in the html body:

```
<noscript>
  <style type='text/css'>
    area {display:none}
  </style>
</noscript>
```

but the area coordinates still show underneath the image. How can I completely hide them (preferably using pure css or pure javascript)?

Comment: just don't show them by default and show them via javascript

Comment: How do I hide them by default? display:none or visibility:hidden doesn't work, not even on the map tag. I want to keep the image.

Comment: You could duplicate the image, and make the second one without the `usemap` attribute, then toggle the `display: none` in one or another like you are doing.

Comment: An areamap in 2017?

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant idea. Is it possible to use javascript to add the attributes usemap (for the img) or name (for the map)? I have several large image maps and duplicating the image would be quite tedious. I could just remove those attributes by default. I have tried the following but they don't work:

    var mapImage = document.getElementById('imageMap');
    var att = document.createAttribute('usemap');
    att.value = '#mapmap';
    mapImage.setAttributeNode(att);

or

    document.getElementsByTagName("map").setAttribute("name", "mapmap");

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having an image map be disabled if JavaScript isn't available, why not enable it only if JavaScript is available? Since you only want the map to appear is JS is enabled, JS can be used to enable it. Browsers with JS disabled will be unable to run the code and will only display the image.

```
var myMappedImages = document.getElementsByClassName("myMappedImage");
for(var i=0,len=myMappedImages.length;i<len;i++){
    myMappedImages[i].usemap = "#myimagemap";
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it could not add the usemap attribute. I also did this but no effect:

document.getElementById("imageMap").useMap = "#mapmap";